# Unable to use netTCP binding for core service

Tags: 2011, core-service

For one of the custom application, trying to connect to coreservice using netTcp binding (`net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/2011/netTcp`) which is faster than basichttp binding. However, when I try to retrieve results using nettcp binded client, I am getting following error:

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:30:00'.

Can you please suggest what am I missing?

Comment: Please update your question with netTcp Binding configuration form your application's config file.

Comment: Check the Event Viewer on the CM server, for errors related to your request. I'm assuming the problem is with a mismatch in bindings between the server and client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was problem with the configuration for netTCP binding. Found reference from the blog: http://rjin-tridion.blogspot.com/

Following the steps mentioned in the article resolved my issue. Now, I am able to connect and get results from core service.

Comment: Can you please tell exactly what change you did and in which file to fix this issue ?, not able to find any relevant fix the link you pasted for reference blog in above comment

Comment: Please refer the link: http://rjin-tridion.blogspot.com/search?updated-max=2012-10-30T13:16:00-07:00&max-results=7

Answer (score 3):

The exception says about the receiveTimeout, but It could be misleading sometimes and the issue is with something else.

based on my experience with tridion core service, it could be with `maxBufferSize` `maxBufferPoolSize` `maxReceivedMessageSize` `readerQuotas` for the binding.

This Could be a possible duplicate of the issue
[Tridion 2011 SP1 Core Service Timeouts](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3506/tridion-2011-sp1-core-service-timeouts)

Below link could be useful as well

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919287/wcf-windows-service-timeout